# How to successfully run Javascript in Atom

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, atom-editor, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run this code in Atom so I can print out the contents of events:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('/i 
Messenger/{Messages}/{id}').onWrite(event => {
console.log(event)
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title:'New message arrived',
    body:'Hello World',
    badge:'1',
    sound:'default',
    }
};
  return admin.database().ref('/i 
Messenger/{Messages}/{id}/UserDeviceToken').once('value').then(allToken => {
    if (allToken.val()){
      const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {

    });
  }
});
});
```

But I the console ever return is: bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[Finished in 0.013s]

Even if there was no script the console would still return the same as above. Anyone know what's wrong here as I don't know much about JavaScript or Atom?

Comment: **How** do you run the code in atom?

Comment: Well, I changed to a package called Script Runner. That actually seems to run but now I have an error: "Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function."
From what I read, it doesn't seem to be possible to run cloud functions from Atom with out some sort of extra commands... Basically, I want to run this javascript file to see what data I have access to in the 'event', which has been surprisingly difficult to do.

Comment: I've never tried running Cloud Functions from within Atom. I recommend using the dedicated emulator and shell, both using the Firebase CLI: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator.

Comment: @frank thanks. I was able to solve this issue. It was actually pretty simple, I just didn’t where to look... instead to trying to run the script from Atom to see the contents of events I should have been looking at the cloud function logs on firebase.